# Intercept ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP but still send to children views

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, viewgroup

I'm extending `LinearLayout` and overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` because I want to receive all touch event on all children views. I'm only interested in receiving the `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` `MotionEvent`s. I still want the children view to receive all the events.

The problem I found is that if

- Return false from `onInterceptTouchEvent`: all subsequent `MotionEvent`s are sent to the children views and I will not receive `ACTION_UP`.
- Return true from `onInterceptTouchEvent`:  all subsequent `MotionEvent`s are sent to my `onTouchEvent` view and the children views will not receive any.

  ```
  class LinearLayout : android.widget.LinearLayout {

      constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
      constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet)
      constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr)
      constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

      override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean  {
          Log.d("LinearLayout", "onInterceptTouchEvent >> $event")
          return when (event.action) {
              MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> true // or false
              MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> true
              else -> false
          }
      }

      override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
          Log.d("LinearLayout", "onTouchEvent >> $event")
          return true
      }
  }
  ```

Is there any way to intercept all `MotionEvent`s and send them all to the children views? If not, is there any other way to intercept all touch events over a `ViewGroup`?

Comment: `boolean View#dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`?

Comment: @pskink Was testing it :) I have to return `super.dispatchTouchEvent` for it to work. If you answer I will accept it.

Comment: sure you have to call super class implementation but i have no idea about how it is done in kotlin so i just named a method that dispatches every `MotionEvent`

Comment: @pskink It is done the same as Java `return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)` :) You can just post the answer in Java, it's ok.